# OnReceive not called inside BroadcastReceiver object in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to create a BroadcastReceiver which should trigger when the device language is changed while the app is running in background. I created a method to recreate the Activity when the language is changed and I call it inside onReceive from BroadcastReceiver. But the problem is onReceive it's not called and I don't know why.

 I know there are other topics on this subject but couldn't find a proper solution. Thanks

**setupLanguageReceiver() method**

```
private fun setupLangReceiver(): BroadcastReceiver? {

    if (mLangReceiver == null) {
        mLangReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {                 
                recreateActivity(intent)
            }
        }
        this@PrbModuleActivity.registerReceiver(mLangReceiver, IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED))
    }
    return mLangReceiver
}
```

**recreateActivity() method**

```
 private fun recreateActivity(intent: Intent) {
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION)
    this@PrbModuleActivity.finish()
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0)
    startActivity(intent)
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0)
}
```

**I call the setupLangReceiver() method inside onResume() and unregisterReceiver inside onPause()**

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    setupLangReceiver()
}

override fun onPause() {
    if(mLangReceiver != null) {
        unregisterReceiver(mLangReceiver)
        mLangReceiver = null
    }
    super.onPause()
}
```

Comment: Your code is set to trigger when the device language is changed while the app is running in the *foreground*. You register the receiver in `onResume()`, which is called when the activity becomes eligible for input as part of moving to the foreground. You unregister the receiver in `onPause()`, which is called when the activity loses input focus as part of moving to the background.

Comment: @CommonsWare and what should I change?..

Comment: Personally, I would not do what you are doing. Your activity should be destroyed and recreated automatically on a configuration change, which includes a locale change. So, rather than doing that manually yourself, you should determine why this is not working for you (e.g., check `android:configChanges` for this activity in your manifest).

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you give me an example of code for this, please? Thanks